# Co prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

How to find a set of numbers which are coprime to each other (all numbers are pairwise co prime) ?

the numbers can be assumed to be less than a specific integers.
like all numbers in the range [0,x]

Comment: The simplest such set is the empty set. The next simplest is any single number in the range.

Comment: How about all the prime numbers in $[1,x]$ including $1$?

Comment: {1,3,4} is also such set but 4 is not prime. (if x>=4)

Comment: @SayanGhosh All you asked for was *any* set of such numbers. You did not ask for the largest set.

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked before?

Comment: This question could be a lot clearer. What would go a long way would be for Sayan to give an example for some small value of $x$, e.g., $x = 10$.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat numbers $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ are pairwise coprime, see [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123524/fermat-numbers-are-coprime). This is a nice example. Of course, there are many others, for example the set of all prime numbers.