# Finding the HCF

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Find $(a^{2^m}+1, a^{2^n}+1)$ when a is odd and a,m,n are positive integers and m is not equal to n. I know that the hcf is a multiple of two but I can't prove that it is 2 which is the answer. Plz help.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123524/fermat-numbers-are-coprime

Comment: Since $a$ is even, both the numbers are odd, so the HCF can't be $2$.

Comment: Special case of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983281/242) where $\,2\nmid b-c,\,$  so the gcd  $ =(a+1,2) = 2\ $ by $a$ odd.

Answer (score 0):

a is odd, let $a=2k+1$ then:

$a^{2^m}+1=(2k+1)^{2^m}+1= 2t+2=2(t+1)$

Where due to binomial theorem t is a sum with factors $(2k)^i$ and $2^m$. Similarly we have:

$a^{2^n}+1=(2k+1)^{2^n}+1= 2s+2=2(s+1)$

Where s is the sum of terms like $(2k)^i C^{2^n}_i$. Therefore we may write:

$(a^{2m}+1, a^{2^n}+1)=2$