# Problems regarding GCD

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $m > n$ and $a,m,n$ are positive, with $m$ not equal to $n$, find the 
greatest common divisor of $2^{2^m}+1, 2^{2^n}+1$. Please solve this problem using Euclid's algorithm.

I tried to use Euclid's algorithm by first dividing $2^{2^m}+1$ by $2^{2^n}+1$, but I got stuck in the 2nd step while dividing $2^{2^n}+1$ by the difference of $2^{2^m}+1$ and $2^{2^n}+1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123524/fermat-numbers-are-coprime

Comment: There is no such thing as a "greatest common denominator". Two fractions will have a *least* common denominator. Two integers will have a greatest common *divisor*. Anyway, do you know what Euclid's Algorithm is? Do you know how to apply it? Where do you get stuck when you try to apply it to this question? We can't help you, if we don't know what you can do, and what you can't do.

Comment: As written, the answer is $(a^2)^{n+1}$, obviously. PLease check the statement

Comment: @Hagen, look at the edit history. A comedy of errors.

Comment: @Garry and Hagen, sorry for the confusion that I have caused. Being new to this website, I have many things to learn. I have rightly edited the problem now and if you can, please help me.

Comment: Have you not noticed, Rohan, that your question has been closed? That means no one can post an answer. But, luckily for you, it has been closed as a duplicate, and a link has been furnished to the earlier question (in fact, to *three* earlier questions) that your question duplicates. So have a look at those three earlier questions, and see whether they settle things for you.

Comment: @Garry Sorry again :(

Comment: So, have you had a look at those earlier questions, Rohan? Are things settled now?

Comment: @Garry Thanks for asking. I am now clear on this topic. I am now trying to further improve my understanding on Euclid's algorithm by solving more problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

The first step in Euclid's algorithm:

If we let $a_k = 2^{2^k}+1$, and

$$g(m,n)=\sum _{j=1}^{2^{m-n}} (-1)^{j+1}2^{2^m-j 2^n}$$

then

$$a_m=a_ng(m,n)+2$$

The second step would be

$$a_n=2\left(\frac{a_n-1}{2}\right)+1$$

which shows that $a_m,a_n$ are coprime for $m>n>0$