# If $m>n$ prove that $a^{2^n}+1$ is a divisor of $a^{2^m}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have to prove that $a^{2^n} +1\mid a^{2^m}-1$ when $m>n$.

What I've done: I considered the two cases when $a= 2k$ and when $a= 2k+1$.

Comment: And what did you get in those two cases?

Comment: Do you mean $a^{2^{n+1}}$ or $a^{2^{n}+1}$ or $a^{2^{n}}+1$?

Comment: @AndrewChin The first two interpretations seem to make the problem too easy (though the first hits issues if $m=n+1$) so I would guess the third was intended comparing $a^{2^{n}}+1$ and $a^{2^{m}}-1$

Comment: See my post in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123524/fermat-numbers-are-coprime

Comment: It's  a^2^n  +   1.   1 is not in the power

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1)$.

A bigger hint:

> $x^{2^n} - 1 = ( x^{2^{n-1}} -1 ) ( x^{2^{n-1}} + 1)$

Comment: Please  give me  solution.  I am totally clueless  about this question

Comment: What have you tried? Can you prove it for $m=n+1$ using the first hint? How about for $m=n+2$ using the second hint too?

Comment: How can you say m=n+1. Or m=n+2.     Sir please  give me the proper solution .  I will be very thankful to you